# What is the most common way to pronounce 運?

Tags: readings, colloquial-language, phonology

So 運 is spelled うん, but I seem to hear most of my friends pronounce it as　あん. My friends and family are 20-60 years of age and come from mostly Tokyo and Ibaraki area. I am living in the US now and so am not speaking much Japanese, but I remember trying to pronounce it as  うん and being misunderstood till I pronounced it as あん (or maybe more like a nasal ahn).  Is this a regional dialect? Does anyone pronounce it as うん? Which way should I pronounce it to be understood by most Japanese?

Comment: Can you describe the geographical location and the context?

Comment: I pronounce it as `うん`.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you quite sure that it was あん (with a vowel at the front) and not just ん or んー?

Comment: Yeah. the weird thing is i didnt remember this until i saw a japanese speaker write a journal entry in english where she wrote it with the romaji spelling An. I thought to myself why didnt she write Un, but then i remember the few times i had encountered it myself. I guess I'll ask my friends.

Comment: Probably `運が多い` is a typo of `運がよい` or something else.

Comment: Typically (but not always), Americans have problem pronouncing the word-initial "u" sound, and they tend to insert "y" in front of it. Thus, the Japanese words like `うら`, `うすい` are tend to be pronounced by Americans as "yura", "yusui". It might be the case that you were not actually pronouncing 運 as うん but were pronouncing it as "yun", and the Japanese people misunderstood it.

Comment: so 運が多い does not make sense?

Comment: 運が多い does not make sense.

Comment: OK i'll delete this question because I am not clear on too many things about it. thank you anyway

Comment: I can just about imagine [ɯɯ̃] being misheard as [ʌn] by an English speaker...

Comment: @ZhenLin: Doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure it is pronounced as Un~

I lived in ibaraki and they used "un" when we discussed it in benkyoukai. Haven't heard "an" used before.